# How to get the top left X and Y in JavaFX to rotate rectangle?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to rotate a JavaFX rectangle. But when I rotated it and try to get it's X and Y this was the same X and Y like before. I use this code: `

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(100,100,40,40); 
r.getX();
r.getY();
r.setRotate(85);
r.getX();
r.getY();    `
```

The getX() and getY() returns the same result before and after the rotate method.
So my question is what can I do to get the top left X and Y in his new location.
Here is an example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVWWq.png)

Comment: Rotation, translation, scale and such are Node properties. They do not touch the original rectangle coordinates, but are combined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know javafx, but I think that when you rotate object then you don't change it's X and Y position. Maybe you should use something like `r.getRotate()`.

Comment: yes, there is r.getRotate() function but its return the degrees of the rotate. and it doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

Use `localToParent` to apply the transformation of the node to the coordinates you want to retrieve instead of using the untransformed coordinates:

```
Point2D transformedPoint = r.localToParent(r.getX(), r.getY());
```

BTW: The `rotate` property rotates around the center of the node. You won't get the result in the image (expecially not rotating by 85°).